# How to find the timepoint when on average each timeseries reaches a given threshold with hypothesis testing?

Tags: r, time-series, hypothesis-testing, change-point, structural-change

I have N individual timeseries and would like test statistically - after the fact - when they cross a given threshold - specifically when they are reliably above 0. I am new to timeseries analysis and did not manage to find the appropriate solution with my keywords so far. I would do this separately per my categorical variable (Type).

Would like to do it in R.

Note: My dependent variable is continuous. The horizontal and vertical lines indicate my region of interest (time>40;threshold>0)
[image: Meand and SE of N timeseries]

Comment: When you say cross a threshold, I assume you do not mean that it has a single negative value, for instance. What, qualitatively, is your criteria for threshold-crossing?

Comment: I've edited the question so that it is clearer that I'm looking for the earliest timepoint -after t.40 - where the mean is above 0. I'm looking for something more sophisticated that doing a t-test on each timepoint, I would want to somehow capture some reliable 0 threshold crossing behavior by modelling it as quadratic timeseries. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes. How were the confidence bounds generated for the image above? Those in a sense give you a probabilistic likelihood of the mean being above zero.

Comment: stat_summary(fun.data=mean_se, ... fun.args = list(mult = 1))

Comment: So they were generated from a statistical procedure. Would you consider setting the alpha at whatever confidence level you want, and then when the lower CI > 0 after t=40 then you've met your threshold. I'm just trying to consider the simple first before suggesting something else.

Comment: Yes, thats a good start I suppose - it's in line with a timepoint-wise t-test approach, right? The reason I'm wary of that approach is that I think it doesn't safeguard against fluctuation observed in the beginning...

Comment: @Chris The problem with the "simple" is that it doesn't perform as expected.  It is not valid to use confidence limits for making a decision about an optimal stopping point: they do not support this interpretation, they are strongly positively correlated, and cannot readily be adjusted for the many comparisons that are involved.  What is needed is a *sequential* test, a *changepoint* test, or application of some quality control procedure such as a control chart.

Comment: Sinandrei, do you need to make this determination in real time or after the fact?

Comment: Luckily offline, after the fact.

Comment: @whuber I'd argue that depends on what is expected. Perhaps I should have said "convenient" instead of simple. The original question also never mentions finding an optimal stopping point. It is just to determine when a threshold is crossed. If other tests aren't necessary to provide a solution then why spend the time developing (and understanding) them?

Comment: @Chris The problem with your proposal is that it is *extremely* wrong, not just sort of right!  The basic phenomenon is explained at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20676/why-is-running-split-tests-until-statistically-significant-a-bad-thing-or-is/20677#20677.  BTW, this is an "optimal stopping" problem in the sense of choosing the first time when something occurs.

Comment: On the picture above it would get you to approximately the right place. Not that anecdotal success makes it theoretically great but my perspective is that of someone working in industry where sometimes I need (because someone else demands) an answer very quickly. It is acceptable to do something *quick-and-dirty* and explain what I might do with more time. If anecdotally something is successful, and it's fast, then sometime that is what I go with as a first pass.

Comment: By chance are these neural data?

Comment: Yes, in a way; I have N subjects' EEG data to which I fit classifier and on the Y axis we see the performance of the classifier - minus 50 - over time.