# Random Variable or not

Tags: probability

I have been reading about probability distribution and random variables and I came across something:

If X is the number of times a coin was actually tossed; is X a Random Variable?

Comment: In most applications, No. The number of tosses $n$ is determined before the coin tossing experiment is done. [For full disclosure: Sometimes, one knows the numbers of heads obtained from several coin tossing experiments with the same unknown number $N$ of tosses and one tries to deduce the value of $N.$ Then $N$ is regarded as a random variable. This is a difficult problem that you are unlikely to encounter in an elementary course.]

Comment: I agree with @BruceET. Just to complicate things a bit, a random variable is a mapping from a given state of the world to real numbers. Thus, if we fix $n$ arbitrarily, then it is not a random variable. However, say we implement a rule, such as tomorrow we will toss 20 coins if it is raining and 25 if the sun will be shining in the sky. Then, today (i.e., prior to the knowledge of the realized state of the world tomorrow) the number of tosses is a random variable (hence denoted by the uppercase $N$).

Comment: At https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/20677/919 I give a familiar example in which the number of coin tosses *can* be a random variable.  Generally, in any *sequential experimental design* the number of observations is random.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the situation I guess. Two simple examples

A) Alice tosses a coin n times and records its value,...

B) For 10 days at the end of each day, if it has rained during the afternoon, Bob tosses a coin...

I would say in case A the number of tosses is not a random variable, in case B it is.

(Technically speaking you could consider also in case A) a random variable having degenerate distribution in n, but I don't think it would help you understand the concept)