Source to explain my bosses basic things about statistics
I'm working for a global multi-billion dollar company with a safety-relevant machine. During development of that machinery product we have a strategy to test for machine reliability.
I had to review that strategy and in my eyes, I think it's very flawed (I'm no statistician, I'm more or less a layperson). When bringing that up (very softly), I was attacked quite aggressively by my bosses 1 and even 2 levels above my level. I need now credible and easy-to-understand book sources, best rooted in reliability statistics.
The issue is, they want to test the product for a specific error rate lambda or better and have a fixed-time demonstration test for it for 95% confidence. So far so good. But my bosses think they can perform the test n times (let's say n=20 times), stop at any point n_i when the desired result result_i is reached and still believe that specific result with 95% confidence.
Additionally they think that you must not obey a testing time T (for a fixed-time test formula), you can just go along with T from zero to ad infinitum and stop at any point when the desired result would be reached. I think you would then have to apply something like sequential testing formulae, but they do not do that. For me those are two methods of cherrypicking.
How can I convince them with a reliable and clear-to-read source that you have to be careful with that? I even developed myself a simple Monte Carlo reliability model where you can clearly see how the confidence level drops with their method, but they don't understand or believe it. I also tried to talk theory, but the answer is "What you are bringing up, is purely theoretic" in a tone as if theory is a despised thing with no connection to reality. They believe statistics books with a skew to engineering (e.g. Birolini), but I did not find clear enough statements in Birolini (clear enough for my bosses) about the pre- and side conditions which you have to obey to make a specific statistic test valid.
Another thing I thought about is to hire a credible external statistician to back up my claims, but I would have to pay that privately. Besides book sources, does anyone have knowledge or experience with that?
Thanks for your help in advance

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Dear Community Bot, what I need is: A reliable source (+ maybe a review/feedback if I am completely wrong with my view). I am not sure if I can dump down my question more without loosing important context.

Actually, do NOT dumb it down, but add details. What is being measured 20 times? Numerical or categorical? What type of test is being used? Etc...

As a start, look at the National Institute of Standards and Technology web site on product monitoring and control. I'm not sure that it has a direct example for your case, but it makes the general principles pretty clear. With respect to clarifying your question, it might help to state the main question clearly at the beginning, something like "What are the risks of stopping a quality control process once a certain failure rate or better has been achieved? Are confidence intervals on the failure rate reliable with that type of stopping?"

This answer on this subject of "curtailment" might also help with references and links, although it's almost 10 years old.

This page might also help.

We have threads about this, including https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20676 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/310119.

Thanks a lot for your help! I advanced with my topic (writing a fairly long review) also using the sources you provided. So this question from my end could be closed.
